# Increasing font size using JavaScript on html

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am having a problem while studying JavaScript.

I tried to make the font larger when I click the second button, but it does not work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>What can Javascript do?</h2>
  
  <p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
  
  <button type = "button" onclick = 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Change Text!</button>
  <button type = "button" onclick = 'document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize='45px''>Bigger Font!</button>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Q. Could you let me know the proper way of implementing the button?

Q. What should I do if I want 2 functions in the same button?

Thank you very much for it!

Comment: This is not a perfect way to apply CSS, what if you add few more properties like to set background color, height and width etc. The will become lengthy and not easy to understand also. Why don't you use style tag to set the CSS? Or JavaScript function to the work of apply CSS

Comment: @PrashantPimpale You are right! It needed different approach. I will study for it. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes are the problem. The single quotes makes the compiler, to compile it as `document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize=`, as the first closing quotes strikes in.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>What can Javascript do?</h2>
  
  <p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
  
  <button type = "button" onclick = 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Change Text!</button>
  <button type = "button" onclick = 'document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize="45px"'>Bigger Font!</button>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked very well. From now on, I will consider the difference of ''' and '"', so that it won't make any mistake. Thank you.

Comment: And thanks for letting me know how its compiler works when it meet those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your original code, since you used single quote to wrap the attribute value, you need to use double quote inside it, just like how you used it on the first function

```html
<h2>What can Javascript do?</h2>
<p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!"'>Change Text!</button>
<button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize="45px"'>Bigger Font!</button>
```

But normally, attribute values are wrapped in double quotes instead. The answer to you second question I think would be to create a function that calls those two functions

One more thing, it would be really better if you create a function first then call that instead

Comment: Thank you. it helped a lot. I will make functions, and apply it to the button. Your suggestion will make the code more clear, and simple. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create a function, then call that function with an event (click) from the button.

```
<script>
function dostuff(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize='45px';
}
</script>

<button type = "button" onclick='dostuff'>Change Text + Bigger Font!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems much clear and better than original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do both, you can insert the command after `;` in `onclick = '...'`!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>What can Javascript do?</h2>
  
  <p id="demo">JavaScript can change HTML content.</p>
  
  <button type = "button" onclick = 'document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";document.getElementById("demo").style.fontSize="45px"'>Do both!</button>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried using ';' before, but I found that my current trial of using ';' was on the wrong order. Your answer helped.